# How to get only one from each value in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
    r.rev_id, rs.name, COUNT(ws.user_id) as likes 
FROM 
    Reviews AS r 
LEFT JOIN
    Wasliked AS ws ON r.rev_id = ws.rev_id 
LEFT JOIN  
    Restaurants AS rs ON rs.rid = r.rest_id
GROUP BY 
    rs.name, r.rev_id
ORDER BY 
    likes DESC
```

and the result is:

```
rev_id    name    likes
------------------------
  7       rest1     5
  10      rest1     3
  6       rest1     2
  2       rest3     2
  1       rest2     2
  5       rest3     1
  8       rest4     1
```

But I want the result to be like this:

```
rev_id    name    likes
--------------------------
  7       rest1     5
  2       rest3     2
  1       rest2     2
```

taking the 3 highest results with different names.

I have already tried to only `group by rs.name` instead of `rs.name,r.rev_id` but that causes an error.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

So you want the top value for each name, limited to three rows.  This suggest `row_number()`:

```
SELECT TOP 3 rev_id, name, likes
FROM (SELECT r.rev_id, rs.name, COUNT(ws.user_id) as likes, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY rs.name ORDER BY COUNT(ws.user_id)) as seqnum 
      FROM Reviews r left join
           Wasliked ws 
           on r.rev_id = ws.rev_id left join
           Restaurants rs
           on rs.rid = r.rest_id
      GROUP BY rs.name, r.rev_id
     ) x
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY likes desc;
```

Comment: It still doesnt work, showing wrong results with the same name

Answer (score 0):

Also you can do it like this if you do not mind writing a redundant sql:

```
select top 3 t1.*
from (  
    select r.rev_id, rs.name, count(ws.user_id) as likes
    from reviews as r
    left join wasliked as ws on r.rev_id=ws.rev_id
    left join restaurants as rs on rs.rid=r.rest_id
    group by rs.name,r.rev_id
) t1
inner join (
    select name, max(likes) as likes
    from (
        select r.rev_id, rs.name, count(ws.user_id) as likes
        from reviews as r
        left join wasliked as ws on r.rev_id=ws.rev_id
        left join restaurants as rs on rs.rid=r.rest_id
        group by rs.name,r.rev_id) tmp
    group by name
) t2 on t1.name = t2.name and t1.likes = t2.likes
order by t1.likes desc
```

@Gordon Linoff's answer is a better way to do this, his sql is just right, and you could find it gives you the lowest `likes` row per `name`, so when you change

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY rs.name ORDER BY COUNT(ws.user_id)) as seqnum
```

to

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY rs.name ORDER BY COUNT(ws.user_id) DESC) as seqnum
```

it will give you the right result.

Answer (score 0):

Your query has the form *show rows with max(foo)*.  The first line of attack is Group By, but sometimes, you want more information about the aggregate.  In this case, having computed **likes** by *rev_id* and *name*, you want only those rows having **max(likes)** for each name.  That calls for an existence test:

```
with T (rev_id, name, likes) as (
  SELECT r.rev_id, rs.name, COUNT(ws.user_id) as likes 
    FROM Reviews as r
    left join Wasliked as ws on r.rev_id=ws.rev_id
    left join Restaurants as rs on rs.rid=r.rest_id
    GROUP BY rs.name,r.rev_id
)
select * from T as L
where exists (
      select 1 from T
      where name = L.name
      group by name
      having max(likes) = L.likes
)
order by likes desc
```

That's about right.

I prefer my version to the others provided so far.  It doesn't use the nonstandard `top N` formulation, and the query is cast in terms of the logical operation you need, i.e. quantification.

With practice, `where exists` gets easier, and will save you writing many more complicated queries.